# Integrals of $2\pi$-periodic functions

Tags: integration

Let $f,g,h$ be continuous $2\pi$-periodic functions. In a certain proof the following step is used, and I am having my doubts about it. Is $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x-t-y)g(t)h(y)dtdy$ equal to $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x-t)g(t-y)h(y)dtdy$? And if so, why?

Comment: It might become clearer if you rename $t$ to $u$ in the second integral.